# Character stays in T-pose after animating

Tags: animation, mesh, bones, transforms, parent

I'm kind of new to Blender and started animating a character. After animating it, I animated my second character. Now, my Lightfury (the first character) is stuck in a T-pose, and some of the animations are still there, but the open mouth is now closed, and the bones have changed. The character doesn't move anymore with the bones (stuck in T-pose). What happened, and how do I fix this problem?
is the mesh not connected with the bones anymore?

the first picture shows the character before the problem and the second with the problem

[image: here is the character before the problem]

[image: here is the character with the problem]

Comment: Visit the armature settings and be sure that Pose is highlighted, instead of Rest Position.